# Want to open Cosgnos 11 new page by using window.open script

Tags: javascript, cognos, url-parameters

I have some problems with **cognos 11**.
I want to popup **cognos 11** specific page on new window using **javascript** `window.open().`
But I cannot find url parameters, or methods...It was really huge annoying.
Please help me...I need your guy's help.

Also, I already use `iframe` url or sharing url thou..

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to open a particular object, like a report or dashboard, from an external system, portal, etc. [this URL API reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEP7J_11.0.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.wig_cr.doc/c_wig_cr_create_custom_url.html) would likely be helpful.  If you are trying to open some other "[C]ognos 11 specific page," it would be helpful to know what kind.  Also note that in more recent versions of Cognos 11 (maybe R4 and newer?), the "Share" option will generate a link you can use to link directly to an object in the content store.